# Converting direct Date to String using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, dataformat

I know this is probably a stupid question, but I am having the hardest time converting a Date to a string using `SimpleDateFormat`.  I have a local date

> "Thu Jul 18 18:56:51 PDT 2013"

And I am trying to convert it directly in the format

> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss".

What I want the string to look like is this :

> "2013-07-18T18:56:51"

what I am getting is this:

> "2013-07-18T06:56:51"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `hh` use `HH`. `h` is for hour in am/pm, and `H` is for hour in a day.

Comment: @RameshK: No, that's still got `hh` instead of `HH`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `hh`, which is the 12-hour clock. You want to use `HH` instead:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

From the [docs for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> - hh - Hour in am/pm (1-12)
> - HH - Hour in day (0-23)
> - kk - Hour in day (1-24)
> - KK - Hour in am/pm (0-11)

(Quite why they reversed the capitalization in terms of 12/24 hours for `kk`/`KK` is beyond me, but then the whole of the Java date/time API is crazy...)

Also, while it looks like you're currently okay, it's worth thinking about the time zone aspect. A `Date` doesn't have any concept of a time zone or calendar - it's just an instant in time. The `SimpleDateFormat` *does* have an associated time zone and calendar (and culture) so make sure they're correct for your purposes.

Comment: For more information check [Date and time patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo: Yup, was just linking to that - or rather the JDK 7 version. Had you noticed the weirdness of kk/KK before? (I point it out in the answer now.)

Comment: Holy gesus. This is heights of inconsistency. Noticed `kk/KK` for the first time. Seems like they were tired enough while create API for `Date`. This is why Joda Time is far better.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I just noticed it right now... that's weird and crazy.

Answer (score 0):

**h**   Hour in am/pm (1-12)

**H**   Hour in day (0-23)

**k**   Hour in day (1-24)

**K**   Hour in am/pm (0-11)

use HH

[Class SimpleDateFormat doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must use `HH` rather than `hh`:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples

H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0

k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24

K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0

h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12

You can read more about `Date` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

package com.stackoverflow.experiments;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class SimpleDateFormatExperiment {

```
/**
 * 
 */
public SimpleDateFormatExperiment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
}
```

}